# Retrieve all objects of the same specific class from an abstract class

Tags: java, object-oriented

I have an abstract class called `ProjectItem` and I have 2 specific classes. One of them is called `Task` and the other is called `Deliverable`.

I have to put all the `ProjectItem`s inside a list, which I did, and I also need to put all the `ProjectItem`s that are `Deliverable` inside another list.

My approach is to, so to say, detect the `ProjectItem`s that are also being extended by a `Deliverable` and put them in a list. I have tried using a for loop like this:

```
public List<ProjectItem> projectItems = new ArrayList<ProjectItem>();
public List<Deliverable> allDeliverables = new ArrayList<Deliverable>();

public List<Deliverable> allDeliverables() {
    for(ProjectItem pItem : projectItems) {
        if(pItem instanceof Deliverable) {
            allDeliverables.add(pItem);
        }
    }

    return allDeliverables;
}
```

The thing is that I get an error because `allDeliverables` as a list accepts only `Deliverable` and also the use of `instanceof` is not correct but I don't see any other way around.

Comment: I'm no Java expert, but shouldn't you be casting pItem to Deliverable? allDeliverables.add((Deliverable) pItem);

Comment: And your for-loop should probably use an object instead of ProjectItem: for(Object pItem : projectItems)

Comment: Btw I think the question is a better fit for stackoverflow

Comment: If you call the `allDeliverables` method twice, you'll re-add deliverable project items to the list.  It might be better to add them to the list as they are created or put onto the project items list rather than waiting until later.  If you can, use tell instead of ask -- for example, tell the items to add themselves to the proper list(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to cast `pItem` to `Deliverable` using `allDeliverables.add((Deliverable) pItem);`

I can not stress enough how helpful IDEs are in dealing with this. For example, eclipse offers you this as an easy quick fix (the first one):

[image: Eclipse offers the cast as a quick fix]

All other IDEs should offer similar suggestions, if you are using an IDE that doesn't offer this as a trivial fix, ditch it and use a better one.

In the future, [once pattern matching is a proper feature of the language (slated for Java 16)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/375), you will be able to leverage it as this is one of the classical examples (`instanceof`, then casting) for which it is designed:

```java
if (pItem instanceof Deliverable deliverable){
    allDeliverables.add(deliverable);
}
```

Another option is to use streams and filter out incompatible classes, then map to the correct type, then collect:

```java
public List<Deliverable> allDeliverables(){
    return projectItems.stream()
        .filter(Deliverable.class::isInstance)
        .map(Deliverable.class::cast)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Polygnome is correct an a practical approach to your problem.
I especially like the the "streams approach".

However, I'd like to show a more  OO-ish approach:

```
private static final
Biconsumer<Collection<? extends ProductItem>, ProductItem> DO_NOTHING = (l,i)->{;};
private final    
Map<Class<?>,BiConsumer<Collection<? extends ProductItem>, ProductItem>> itemCollectors = new HashMap<>();

// in constructor
itemCollectors.put(Deliverable.class,(list,item)-> list.add(item));

public List<Deliverable> allDeliverables(){
   for(ProjectItem pItem : projectItems)
      itemCollectors.getOrDefault(pItem.getClass(),DO_NOTHING)
                    .accept(allDeliverables,pItem)
   }
}
```

---

Alternatively the concrete classes could know themselves if they would be part of the collection or not:

Class `ProjectItem` would define another abstract method:

```
abstract public <T extends ProjectItem> void addTo(Collection<T> theCollection);
```

The concrete classes would implement it as needed:

```
// non deliverable sub class
public <NonDeliverable> void addTo(Collection<NonDeliverable>  theCollection){
} //  just empty


//  deliverable sub class
public <Deliverable> void addTo(Collection<Deliverable>  theCollection){
   theCollection.add(this);
}

// usage
public List<Deliverable> allDeliverables(){
   for(ProjectItem pItem : projectItems)
     pItem.addTo(allDeliverables);
   }
}
```